# What action/filter/function determines "current" class in WP Admin Menu

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu

I have created a submenu page for the Media List Table. The link actually points to a custom view I have created called Resources. I am looking for the correct location where the Admin menu determines what page(s) are highlighted as "current", and cannot seem to find where I could access this.

```
add_media_page( __( 'Resources', ZG_TEXTDOMAIN ), __( 'Resources', ZG_TEXTDOMAIN ), 'read', 'upload.php?resources=1' );
```

Here is an image of the Resources menu item being clicked, the URL reading as `/wp-admin/upload.php?resource=1`, but the menu is obviously not being highlighted properly.

[image]

Quite an odd request, as it's not it's on page, but the current path does match the menu slug, so I'm not seeing where the issue lies.

Comment: I can tell you this is called in `wp-admin/menu-header.php` on lines 132- 141. I can't however tell you how to fix this after playing around with it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right path, Wyck! I was looking for where it was created, but couldn't find it, and had to move onto something else quick.

Comment: Not looking like there is a way to accomplish this. There are no filters, and I cannot change the url to be anything different. I think a lot of the walkers need to be revisited.